# How to convert UInt16 or bytes into heart beat rate in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, heartrate, react-native-ble-plx

I'm trying to read the heart beat rate from my Fitbit Versa Lite Smart Watch from my React-Native application, i was able to get the characteristics of the heart rate and was able to get the value in encoded base64 format like below

```
Heart Rate Data: AAAAAAAAuQAA
```

when i decoded the base64 string, it is showing me as

```
 Heart Rate Data: ¹
```

after having a look into the bluetooth heart rate specifications from the below link

https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml

```
 <Bit index="0" size="1" name="Heart Rate Value Format bit">
  <Enumerations>
   <Enumeration key="0" value="Heart Rate Value Format is set to UINT8. Units: beats per  
      minute (bpm)" requires="C1"/>
   <Enumeration key="1" value="Heart Rate Value Format is set to UINT16. Units: beats per 
      minute (bpm)" requires="C2"/>
  </Enumerations>
 </Bit>

 <Field name="Heart Rate Measurement Value (uint16)">
   <InformativeText> Note: The format of the Heart Rate Measurement Value field is dependent 
    upon bit 0 of the Flags field. </InformativeText>
   <Requirement>C2</Requirement>
   <Format>uint16</Format>
   <Unit>org.bluetooth.unit.period.beats_per_minute</Unit>
 </Field>
```

now considering the above explanation from the link, do i need to consider the 1 as unit of measurement or 1 as the Bytes of data which i received from the heart rate sensor.

React-Native Code for reading the characteristics:

```
async readData(device) {
  const services = await device.services();
  console.log("Services:",services);
  const characteristics = await services[1].characteristics();
  // console.log(JSON.stringify(characteristicW));
  console.log("Characteristics:",characteristics);
 characteristics[0].monitor((err, update) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(`characteristic error: ${err}`);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
   } else {
    console.log("Is Characteristics Readable:",update.isReadable);
    console.log("Heart Rate Data:",base64.decode(update.value));
    var data = new Uint16Array(base64.decode(update.value));
    console.log("Heart Beats:",data[1]);
   }
 });
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm guessing that as that is the superscript 1 character, there's something else going on. Are you using the heart rate library from https://dev.fitbit.com/build/guides/sensors/heart-rate/?

Comment: @CharlesBamford Have updated my post with code which reads the characteristics. Am i doing something wrong? I'm using react-native-ble-plx library from polidea.

Comment: In your code, I don't see how you are getting the "Flags" attribute, and then how you are taking that value and extracting the first **bit** (not byte).

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your output from `base64.decode(update.value)` is ¹.  That is the Unicode representation of [hex value 0xB9, or decimal value 185](https://unicodelookup.com/#%C2%B9/1).

Not clear to me from your code that this is the appropriate way to decipher the Characteristic you are getting in `update`.  Maybe have your code be closer to the [example documented in the wiki](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx/wiki/=--FAQ:-Passing-And-Retrieving-Of-Characteristic-Value#reading-value-from-a-characteristic)?

Comment: I wonder if his heart beat rate was 185 beats per minute.